# Set a coupon description in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

My site dynamically gives users coupons if they have been a member for a long enough time. When I am generating the coupon I want to assign a description to the coupon. However, I seem to be unable to assign a description by updating the post's metadata with the key `description` as the [docs](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Coupon-Data) suggest I should be able to.

Currently I am trying to assign the description like so:

```
$percent = 25;//DISCOUNT PERCENTAGE
$coupon_code = 'testcoupon'; //Coupon Code
$discount_type = 'percent'; // Type: fixed_cart, percent, fixed_product, percent_product

//ASSIGN COUPON AND DISCOUNT PERCENTAGE

$coupon = array(
    'post_title' => $coupon_code,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
);

$new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

// Add meta
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type );//SET DICOUNT TO BE PERCENTAGE BASED
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $percent );//SET DISCOUNT PERCENTAGE
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'yes' );//ONLY ONE CUPON BE USED AT A TIME
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '' ); //INCLUDE ALL PRODUCTS
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '' );//DO NOT EXCLUDE ANY PRODUCTS 
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '1' );//ONE TIME USE
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', strtotime("+6 months") );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no' );//DO NOT GIVE FREE SHIPPING

//ASSIGN DESCRIPTION TO COUPON
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'description', 'This is an example description used for the example coupon');
```

How else should I go about adding a description?

Comment: I have maid an interesting update, using instead the WC_Coupon object and methods to create your coupon…

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! Too bad I cannot give you two +1 s for your answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The coupon description has to be added in the post data as **`post_excerpt`** key *(but not in post meta data)*…

So your code should be instead:

```
$percent = 25;//DISCOUNT PERCENTAGE
$coupon_code = 'testcoupon'; //Coupon Code
$discount_type = 'percent'; // Type: fixed_cart, percent, fixed_product, percent_product
$description = __('This is an example description used for the example coupon');

//ASSIGN COUPON AND DISCOUNT PERCENTAGE

$coupon = array(
    'post_title' => $coupon_code,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_excerpt' => $description, // <== HERE goes the description
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
);

$new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

## … / … and so on
```

Or instead, since WooCommerce 3, you can use any [related method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Coupon.html) on a [`WC_Coupon`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Coupon.html) Object. In your case you will use setter methods to set the data *(as getter methods are used to get the data on an existing coupon object)*:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Coupon object
$wc_coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);

// Some data
$percent = 25; // DISCOUNT PERCENTAGE
$coupon_code = 'testcoupon'; // Coupon Code
$discount_type = 'percent'; // Type: fixed_cart, percent, fixed_product, percent_product
$description = __('This is an example description used for the example coupon'); // Description

// Set the coupon data
$wc_coupon->set_code($coupon_code);
$wc_coupon->set_description($description);
$wc_coupon->set_discount_type($discount_type);
$wc_coupon->set_amount( floatval($percent) );
$wc_coupon->set_individual_use( true );
$wc_coupon->set_usage_limit( 1 );
$wc_coupon->set_date_expires( strtotime("+6 months") );
## $wc_coupon->apply_before_tax( true ); // ==> Deprecated in WC 3+ with no replacement alternatie
$wc_coupon->set_free_shipping( false );

// Test raw data output before save
var_dump($wc_coupon);

// SAVE the coupon
$wc_coupon->save();
```