# Retrieve coupon details from coupon code WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I have previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360869/set-a-coupon-description-in-woocommerce) however it does not answer the question of how to retrieve data from a coupon in WooCommerce. Both questions involve coupons, however, the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360869/set-a-coupon-description-in-woocommerce) is asking how does one set the metadata and this question asks how you retrieve the data.

---

I am trying to get the details of a coupon from WooCommerce by the coupon code. However, I am not sure on how I should try to go about doing this.

I have tried the code below. However, it gives me the error `Call to undefined function WC_Coupon()`

```
$coupon_code = 'save10percent';
global $woocommerce;
$c = WC_Coupon($coupon_code);
```

How should one go about getting the details of a coupon?

Comment: You got **this answer** already is one of **your question answer**: [Set a coupon description in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360869/set-a-coupon-description-in-woocommerce/47361312#47361312) …

Comment: @LoicTheAztec that question is not the same as this post title and question and therefore is not duplicate!

Comment: @HamidAraghi Sorry but the way to get the data is the same, using `WC_Coupon` **getter** methods instead of **setter** methods that this OP asked before… So in both cases you use `WC_Coupon` class methods on the `WC_Coupon` instance object. In My linked answer, I have showed how to get the `WC_Coupon` object and I have added the link to `WC_Coupon` Class available methods… This has also been answered in other threads on how to get coupon data (from orders for example, which is the same process, using `WC_Coupon` getter methods on the `WC_Coupon` Object).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I figured it out. In order for the `WC_Coupon` function to work, I needed to add the "new" keyword prior to calling the function. As demonstrated below.

```
$coupon_code = 'save10percent';
global $woocommerce;
$c = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);
```

Now I can get details about the coupon like so

```
echo "Discount Amount ".$c->amount."<br>";//Get Discount amount
echo "Discount Type ".$c->discount_type."<br>";//Get type of discount
echo "Individual Use ".$c->individual_use."<br>";//Get individual use status
echo "Usage Count ".$c->usage_count."<br>";//Get number of times the coupon has been used
echo "Uage Limit ".$c->usage_limit."<br>";//Get usage limit
echo "Coupon Description ".$c->description."<br>";//Get coupon description
```

Comment: Depending of your context, you cannot access the object directly. Instead, you need to use woocommerce helpers eg: $c->get_amount()

Comment: As @JeffMonteiro said using WooCommerce functions is better I think too. This is what I used. 

```'amount'   => $c->get_amount(),
'date_expires'   => $c->get_date_expires(),
'discount_type'  => $c->get_discount_type(),
'product_ids'   => $c->get_product_ids(),
'excluded_product_ids' => $c->get_excluded_product_ids(),
'usage_count'   => $c->get_usage_count(),
'usage_limit'   => $c->get_usage_limit(),```

Complete list is available here - https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Coupon.html

Thanks OP for the original answer.

Comment: global $woocommerce; is not needed for new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code ), is it?